# What did Freysa mean about Sapper allowing K to kill him?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

This was to keep the secret of the child. But would not killing K have been a good idea? Or did she mean, given that K had won the fight, Sapper forced K to kill him to avoid being taken in and interrogated? But did K suspect anything about the child prior to killing Sapper? Why would Sapper have even mentioned the "miracle?"

Answer (score 5):

Sapper nearly kills K when K comes to kill him (it's hard to square that with "allowing" K to kill him). The key lies in this line from Freysa

> I saw baby come. I held Mama as she die. She die good. She die feeling it. Daddy
> already flew gone before he could see, leaving a puzzle behind. We each hide a
> piece so no one mind ever know enough to make the map. Daddy least of all. Why
> Sapper let you kill him, keep his piece.

To put it another way, there were three people who know of Rachael's child

1. Deckard (the father)
2. Sapper
3. Freysa

All three had fragments of the truth so no one person could spill the secret. Freysa is saying Sapper died to remove his piece from the board (i.e. Rachael's body). He underestimated how thorough K would be in scanning the area.

Comment: did Wallace know of the child?

Comment: It's pretty clear from later scenes that Wallace only learns about the child as a result of K's _subsequent_ investigation, when K digs through Wallace's files to look up Rachel's serial number. So, K's original hunt for Sapper was a run-of-the-mill operation. Prior to this, Wallace believed his only path to breeding Replicants was through his own (as-yet unsuccessful) experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

Neither K nor Wallace knew about the child when K confronted Sapper Morton - it was a routine retirement job. In fact, K didn't even seem to know such a thing was possible until the analysis of the bones. K was sent after Sapper because he popped onto the grid a few months earlier while in the city (as seen in the short prequel film "[Blade Runner 2048: No Where to Run](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ9Os8cP_gg)").

Sapper likely could have killed K had he wanted to, but Sapper had hope for their people and did not like the idea of killing another replicant unless he absolutely had to. When it came down to killing K or being taken in for interrogation, Sapper chose to force K's hand by charging him, knowing full well that the bladerunner would kill him.

As for mentioning the miracle, Sapper gave no details that would alert K to the child's birth - it was simply an offhanded comment that the younger models have no faith in anything, while still expressing Sapper's hope that the younger generations  could change.

Wallace, on the other hand, knew that replicant birth was possible but had so far failed to achieve it. It's likely that he learned of Tyrell's experiments when he took over the company, but the secret to the process itself had died with Tyrell.

Comment: wallace found out how? leak in police department?

Comment: @releseabe - that's probably how he learned about the specific investigation, but Wallace seemed to already know that replicant reproduction was possible. I assume he learned about Tyrell's experiments when he took over the company... he just wasn't able to replicate it since the exact process died with Tyrell. Updated my answer to address that.